# Is it possible to run a command on every individual list item in the order they are placed?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I have a list in python with a random number of items. Is it possible to run the same command on every individual list item in order from 1st to last so that I can convert the output of the command into another list with different variables?

If this is possible than can I create a os.system() command for Mac OS X that runs the OS X afplay command for each individual item again in order from the new list?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question sounds like something you can solve with list comprehensions https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
initial_list = [0, 9, 99, 999]


def increment(value):
    """Increment value by one."""
    value += 1
    return value


# This is a list comprehension, it is basically a for-loop
new_list = [increment(list_item) for list_item in initial_list]

print(f'Old list: {initial_list}')
print(f'New list: {new_list}')
```

Which produces:

```
Old list: [0, 9, 99, 999]
New list: [1, 10, 100, 1000]
```

For your second question, I don't have any experience with Mac OS X, but maybe you could try something like this? I hope this helps you figure it out!

```
import os

audio_files = ['/Media/Sound1.wav', '/Media/Sound2.wav', '/Media/Sound3.wav']

play = [os.system(f'afplay {audio_file}') for audio_file in audio_files]

play[0]  # play the first audio file

# play all the files sequentially
for audio_file in play:
    play[audio_file]
```

EDIT: Now that I read your question again, I think what you want is something like this?

```
import os

audio_files = ['/Media/Sound1.wav', '/Media/Sound2.wav', '/Media/Sound3.wav']

processed_audio_files = [do_something(audio_file) for audio_file in audio_files]

for audio_file in processed_audio_files:
  os.system(f'afplay {audio_file}')
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go and let you know if it works.